# Why doesn't an if constexpr make this core constant expression error disappear?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510531/undefined-behavior-when-constexpr-evaluating-negative-bitshift). The core constant expression that is used to initialize the `constexpr` variable `y` is ill-formed. So much is a given.

But if I try to turn the `if` into an `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    constexpr int x = -1;
    if constexpr (x >= 0){
        constexpr int y = 1 << x;
    }
}

int main(){
    foo<int>();
}
```

The error persists. With GCC 7.2 still giving:

```
error: right operand of shift expression '(1 << -1)' is negative [-fpermissive]
```

But I thought that the semantic check should be left unpreformed on a discarded branch.

Making an indirection via a `constexpr` lambda does help, however:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(){
    constexpr int x = -1;
    constexpr auto p = []() constexpr { return x; };
    if constexpr (x >= 0){
        constexpr int y = 1<<p();
    }
}
```

The `constexpr` specifier on `y` seems to alter how the discarded branch is checked. Is this the intended behavior?

---

**@max66** was kind enough to check other implementations. He reports that the error is reproducible with both GCC (7.2.0 / Head 8.0.0) and Clang (5.0.0 / Head 6.0.0).

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug. Have you tried another implementation?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh - I myself haven't. But the OP of the post I linked reports that [Clang and MSVC behave the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510531/undefined-behavior-when-constexpr-evaluating-negative-bitshift#comment79975550_46510531).

Comment: I confirm the problem with clang++ 3.8.1

Comment: from wanbox I see that the problem still persist with both g++ (7.2.0 and Head 8.0.0) and clang++ (5.0.0 and Head 6.0.0).

Comment: I don't think that "The constexpr specifier on y seems to alter how the discarded branch is checked" because removing that `constexpr` (defining simply "int y = 1 << x;" I don't see errors anymore (I suppose is right, if `y` is initialized runtime) but I see a warning (unused variable `y`); so (if I'm not wrong) that branch is compiled. Or better, I think is right in the meaning that with `constexpr` `y` is initialized compile-time (so `1 << x` is immediately checked) and without is initialized run-time.

Comment: @max66 `int y = 1 << x;` is merely undefined behaviour. Adding `constexpr` makes it ill-formed because UB is not allowed in a constant expression.

Comment: When the question is of the sort "why did the compiler diagnose this ill-formed code that I hoped it won't diagnose", the answer is 90% of the time [temp.res]/8.

Comment: @T.C. - Funny coincidence. I actually quoted that very paragraph under Dietmar's answer. Right about the time his amswer made me go "d'oh!".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard doesn't say much about the *discarded statement* of an `if constexpr`. There are essentially two statements in [stmt.if] about these:

1. In an enclosing template discarded statements are not instantiated.
2. Names referenced from a discarded statement are not required ODR to be defined.

Neither of these applies to your use: the compilers are correct to complain about the `constexpr` if initialisation. Note that you'll need to make the condition dependent on a template parameter when you want to take advantage of the *instantiation* to fail: if the value isn't dependent on a template parameter the failure happens when the template is *defined*. For example, this code still fails:

```
template <typename T>
void f() {
    constexpr int x = -1;
    if constexpr (x >= 0){
        constexpr int y = 1<<x;
    }
}
```

However, if you make `x` dependent on the type `T` it is OK, even when `f` is instantiated with `int`:

```
template <typename T>
void f() {
    constexpr T x = -1;
    if constexpr (x >= 0){
        constexpr int y = 1<<x;
    }
}
int main() {
    f<int>();
}
```

Comment: As I comment to Kerrek, the example in my post is poor. I did verify that it persists after moving the code to a template. The base case still emits an error. Indirection does not. I've update the MCVE. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I updated my response to clarify that only the *instantiation* of the template is affected. The error you get happens during *definition* of the template!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Very good point -- the checking of non-dependent constructions is part of the template definition, not of any one template instantiation, so the non-instantiation of the discarded arm is actually a red herring.

Comment: Mmm.. Yes, I'm starting to see where my understanding went awry. [I also forgot that if no template specialization is valid, for any argument, the program is ill-formed no diagnostic required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#res-8). This addressed my confusion in full.

Answer (score 11):

Note that for the statement discarded by [Constexpr If](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

> the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization:

To fix the issue you can make the statement depending on the template parameter, e.g.

```
template<typename T, int X> struct dependent_value { constexpr static int V = X; };

template <typename T>
void foo() {
    constexpr int x = -1;
    if constexpr (x >= 0){
        constexpr int y = 1 << dependent_value<T, x>::V;
    }
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2XPgvhpY1EGNI7ut)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you expect the branch to not be checked. The only time an if branch is "not checked" is when it is part of a template and not *instantiated*, as per [stmt.if]p2:

> During the instantiation of an enclosing templated
>   entity (Clause 17), if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement
>   (if any) is not instantiated.

Your code doesn't seem to be in a situation where this applies.

Comment: I admit to my [mcve] being poor. [But the error persists after moving the code into a template](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ASFlaJjyMbXqfRtt) (not with a lambda though). So I'll be updating my question. Sorry for invalidating this answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: No worries. It's good to explore new features like this in depth.