# Invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter which is constexpr

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I have a `static_loop` construct like this

```
template <std::size_t n, typename F> void static_loop(F&& f) {
    static_assert(n <= 8 && "static loop size should <= 8");
    if constexpr (n >= 8)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 8>());
    if constexpr (n >= 7)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 7>());
    if constexpr (n >= 6)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 6>());
    if constexpr (n >= 5)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 5>());
    if constexpr (n >= 4)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 4>());
    if constexpr (n >= 3)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 3>());
    if constexpr (n >= 2)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 2>());
    if constexpr (n >= 1)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 1>());
}


template <typename T> constexpr size_t tupleSize(T) { return tuple_size_v<T>; }
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    void run() {
        auto ab = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
        static_loop<tupleSize(ab)>([&](auto i) { std::get<i>(ab) = i; });
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

However, it fails to iterate over a tuple as listed above.

[live godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/OE61J-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: try with

```
// .........VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
static_loop<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(ab)>>([&](auto i) { std::get<i>(ab) = i; });
```

I mean... you can't use `ab` (as value), in a constant expression, because `ab` isn't defined `constexpr`.

And you can't define it `constexpr` because it's initialized using `std::ref()` that isn't `constexpr`.

But you're not interested in `ab` as value to get the size of its type; you're interested only in `ab` type; so you can pass through `decltype(ab)`.

**-- EDIT --**

Off Topic suggestion.

Instead of `static_loop()`, you can use the classic way based on `std::index_sequence` (and template folding, available starting from C++17).

I mean... if you define a `run_1()` function (with `run_1_helper()` helper) as follows

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
void run_1_helper (F const & f, std::tuple<Ts...> & t, std::index_sequence<Is...> const)
 { (f(std::get<Is>(t), Is), ...); }

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void run_1 (F const & f, std::tuple<Ts...> & t)
 { run_1_helper(f, t, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}); }
```

you can write `A` as follows

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    void run() {
        auto ab = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
        run_1([](auto & v, auto i){ v = i; }, ab);
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Or, maybe better, simply using `std::apply()`, as follows

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    void run() {
        auto ab = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
        int i { -1 };
        std::apply([&](auto & ... vs){ ((vs = ++i), ...); }, ab);
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me as `tupleSize` function doens't use `ab` value.

Comment: @Amos - yes, you don't use `ab` value but you pass it to the function; this is enough to break the compile-time compatibility; if you try removing the value (defining `template <typename T> constexpr size_t tupleSize() { return tuple_size_v<T>; }`) and calling it using `decltype()` (`static_loop<tupleSize<decltype(ab)>()>`) you can see that your code works.

Comment: @Amos - Off Topic: why don't you use `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` for your loop? Or `std::apply()`?

Comment: @Amos - do you mean `std::index_sequence()` and `std::apply()` ?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that would work for dispatching over different type of functions. Also I just posted a follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978389/nested-static-loop-fails-to-work-due-to-constexpr-uncapturable

Comment: @Amos - I don't understand what you exactly want in new question (I have to go in this moment; maybe I try to understand it later) but I've added a couple of alternative examples; hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
template <typename T>
constexpr size_t tupleSize(T) { return tuple_size_v<T>; }
```

to:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr size_t tupleSize(T const&) { return tuple_size_v<T>; }
```

That is, take the argument by reference to const, not by value. As-is, you're trying to copy a non-constexpr tuple in a constant expression - that can't work. By reference is fine since you're not actually reading the tuple.