# Nested static loop fails to work due to constexpr uncapturable

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have this `static_loop` construct that is used for type dispatching over loop unrolling.

```
template <std::size_t n, typename F> void static_loop(F&& f) {
    static_assert(n <= 8 && "static loop size should <= 8");
    if constexpr (n >= 8)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 8>());
    if constexpr (n >= 7)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 7>());
    if constexpr (n >= 6)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 6>());
    if constexpr (n >= 5)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 5>());
    if constexpr (n >= 4)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 4>());
    if constexpr (n >= 3)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 3>());
    if constexpr (n >= 2)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 2>());
    if constexpr (n >= 1)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 1>());
}

template <typename T> constexpr size_t tupleSize(T) { return tuple_size_v<T>; }
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    void run() {
        auto ab = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
        static_loop<2>([&](auto i) {
            std::get<i>(ab) = i;
            static_loop<2>([&](auto j) { std::get<i * j>(ab) = i; });
            // static_loop<2>([&, i = std::integral_constant<size_t, i>()](auto j) { std::get<i * j>(ab) = i; });
        });
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

However it doesn't compile when doing nested loops. I'd assume `i` and `j` are both `constexpr` thus `i * j` is valid in `std::get<>`, however, compiler seems not allowing this. Is it possible to capture `i` as constexpr in the inner lambda?

Full example is at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/iIUbDD) along with the error messages.

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978098/invalid-explicitly-specified-argument-for-template-parameter-which-is-constexpr

Comment: [Clang compiles this](https://godbolt.org/z/IBA-eO) but I think it is wrong in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
static_loop<2>([&](auto i) {
    std::get<i>(ab) = i;
    static_loop<2>([&](auto j) { std::get<i * j>(ab) }
}
```

The IDE correctly underlines the error for you. `i * j`is a multiplication of two variables, it is not a compile-time constant.

You can nest loops if you switch to template parameters rather than function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This somehow works. Not sure if it violates any standard rules.

```
template <std::size_t n, typename F> void static_loop(F&& f) {
    static_assert(n <= 8 && "static loop size should <= 8");
    if constexpr (n >= 8)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 8>());
    if constexpr (n >= 7)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 7>());
    if constexpr (n >= 6)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 6>());
    if constexpr (n >= 5)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 5>());
    if constexpr (n >= 4)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 4>());
    if constexpr (n >= 3)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 3>());
    if constexpr (n >= 2)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 2>());
    if constexpr (n >= 1)
        f(std::integral_constant<size_t, n - 1>());
}

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    void run() {
        auto ab = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
        static_loop<2>([&](auto i) {
            std::get<i>(ab) = i;
            static_loop<2>([&](auto j) { auto ii = decltype(i)(); std::get<ii * j>(ab) = ii; });
        });
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The captured value might not be constexpr but its type is somehow retained.