# `if constexpr` with `template` arguments vs. with `constexpr` expressions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

Consider the following definition:

```cpp
template<int n> struct Foo;
template<> struct Foo<1> { void fn1(); };
template<> struct Foo<2> { void fn2(); };
```

`Foo<1>` has a member function `fn1` and similarly `Foo<2>` has `fn2`.  We can use these functions, selecting the appropriate function to call using an `if constexpr` expression:

```cpp
template<int n>
void test_template() {
    Foo<n> foo;
    if constexpr (n==1) {
        foo.fn1();
    } else {
        foo.fn2();
    }
}
template void test_template<1>(); //Interested in `Foo<1>`
```

This works perfectly on latest Clang, GCC, and MSVC.

We can think about doing functionally the same thing, but with a `constexpr` expression:

```cpp
constexpr int n = 1; //Interested in `Foo<1>`
void test_constexpr() {
    Foo<n> foo;
    if constexpr (n==1) {
        foo.fn1();
    } else {
        foo.fn2();
    }
}
```

This fails (on all three compilers)!  Specifically, all compilers' errors show that they are attempting to compile `foo.fn2()`.

Is this behavior correct?  If so, why?  It seems to me like the compilation should be similar, and that the second case should work too!

---

EDIT: several other questions have been asked about `if constexpr` in the context of `template` instantiations (see comments).  However, this is specifically about `if constexpr` *without* `template`s.  Indeed, the `template` version above works as I'd expect.

According to [the C++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

> If the value is `true`, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.

However, it also says:

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive

The question is why this should be the case?

---

<sup>([live example on gcc.godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6neGx571z))</sup>

<sup>(Tagging this C++17, since `if constexpr` is a C++17 feature, though of course I am actually *using* C++20, and soon C++23 . . .)</sup>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46512248/817643

Comment: Read up on [`[temp.res.general]/6.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1).

Comment: `if constexpr` **only** works on things that depend on the template parameters

Comment: These do not appear to be duplicates; they are are all about the discarded statement of an `if constexpr` within a `template`. This is specifically about the discarded statement, when *not* in a `template`.

Comment: @imallett: I don't see why that matters. In a non-template function, *nothing* is a dependent expression, and therefore nothing gets discarded when using `if constexpr`. It's the same reasoning, just with slightly different wording.

Comment: @imallett: "*The question is why this should be the case?*" Because that's how it was defined. `if constexpr` is not *meant* to be a replacement for `#if`.

Comment: @NicolBolas The sections of the specification mentioned by other commenters are *specifically predicated on* being in `template` contexts. You can't arbitrarily remove that predication. In any case, the fact that in `template` contexts the statement *is* discarded suggests that it *would* work, when in fact it does not.¶ To your second comment, that would be answer (albeit I suspect one can generate a less disingenuous justification).

Comment: @imallett: "*the fact that in template contexts the statement is discarded suggests that it would work, when in fact it does not.*" The standard (or an answer) saying that 'Y happens given context X' does not mean Y can happen in other contexts. If it doesn't say that a thing can happen, then it doesn't happen.

Comment: "The question is why this should be the case?" Are you asking about the rationale? The proposal doesn't elaborate on it. Presumably the cost of making it work outside of templates is too big and the benefits are too small to make it worthwhile. But it is best to ask the standard committee members.